# how to get backgroundcolor of iframe ? maybe iframe_window.document?

Tags: html, iframe, background-color

```
..some code here ...

<iframe id="iView" frameborder="0" style="position: relative; z-index: 1500; left: 387px; top: 90px; width: 185px; height: 180px;" name="iView" src="">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(0, 204, 204);"> CONTENT </body>
</html>
</iframe>

..some code here ...
```

i can get the CONTENT with this:

```
iframe_window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
```

anybody know how to get the background color ?
i need to get this:  rgb(0, 204, 204)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
iframe_window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor
```

[backgroundColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530716%28VS.85%29.aspx)